# How I can edit theme in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes

I want to make text on picture a little less bold and italic. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the following content in your setting.json:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "variables": {
      // You can choose bold , italic or underline. If deleted, it will be the default.
      "fontStyle": "bold",
    },
    "functions": {
      // You can choose bold , italic or underline. If deleted, it will be the default.
      "fontStyle": "bold",
    },
```

Comment: you have to limit this to a particular theme name

Comment: Can I do it in bold-italic?